# C++ Distribute data between multiple ts Queues

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, thread-safety, pthreads

I'm trying to distribute a data stream under clients of a multithreaded server instance, the client threads do only need to read. That means I have a thread from which the data comes and all other threads need to read that data (they do not have to change it anymore) so that they can send the data to the clients. For the queue I'm using this: https://blog.chrisd.info/a-simple-thread-safe-queue-for-use-in-multi-threaded-c-applications/ template class.

My approach is to create a list of queues and push the data to all of them. So I can read them in the client thread(one queue for one client thread).

Creating the list:

```
ThreadSafeQueue<std::string> sq[50];
```

Enqueuing the data to all queues:

```
for (i=0; i<50; i++)
{
sq[i].enqueue(buffer);
}
```

Dequeuing the data from one queue per thread:

```
size = sq[local_thread_count].dequeue(res);
```

You can find the whole src code [here](https://github.com/MrGrimod/dji_naza_interface_c-/blob/master/tools/core_gps_deamon/gpsd.cpp)

Each client thread is a [posix thread(`clientHandler`)](https://github.com/MrGrimod/dji_naza_interface_c-/blob/cd9a7931e390c9672cf74dbf80aac2b612be22be/tools/core_gps_deamon/gpsd.cpp#L105) that does nothing else than dequeuing and then sending the information to the clien, the information is pushed in the queue by another [pthread (`gpsDataStream`)](https://github.com/MrGrimod/dji_naza_interface_c-/blob/cd9a7931e390c9672cf74dbf80aac2b612be22be/tools/core_gps_deamon/gpsd.cpp#L123) that reads the information from a serial interface and then enqueues it to all queues.
All the threads are created in the [main function](https://github.com/MrGrimod/dji_naza_interface_c-/blob/cd9a7931e390c9672cf74dbf80aac2b612be22be/tools/core_gps_deamon/gpsd.cpp#L30):

The [`local_thread_count` variable](https://github.com/MrGrimod/dji_naza_interface_c-/blob/cd9a7931e390c9672cf74dbf80aac2b612be22be/tools/core_gps_deamon/gpsd.cpp#L90) is increased by one and passed as parameter when a client thread is created. It's there so each thread dequeues from a different queue.

It works, partly, with one client thread but when adding a second one the first one stops receiving data and only the new one can dequeue data. This shouldn't happen since they both use different queues.

Comment: I agree this shouldn't happen. So maybe you need to show more code.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. How do you create the threads? How do you set the `local_thread_count` variable? What else are the threads doing?

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Your current `clientHandler` implementation prints the value of `local_thread_count`.  Are the values unique for each `clientHandler` instance?

Comment: Sure, they are ;D I already checked that!

Comment: Ok, found the problem. It was not the queues fault, the client thread didn't send it to the first client but only to the second when the first one connected. My mistake :& thx for help